# Solving 2 simultaneous equations with indeces

Tags: probability-distributions, systems-of-equations

I have 3 formulae used to calculate some probabilities of some events, 0, 1, 2 occurring.

P($X=0$) = $(1-$z$)^R$ $\cdot$ $z^A$

P(X = 1) = $0.5^{R+A}$

P(X = 2) = $z^R$ $\cdot$ $(1-$z$)^A$

Where $z$ = 0.01, and $P(X=0) + P(X=1) + P(X=2) = 1$

$R$ and $A$ were known originally and used to calculate the values of $P(X=0),  P(X=1),  P(X=2)$.

I have the set of values corresponding to $P(X=0),  P(X=1),  P(X=2)$, for example, 0.660  0.333  0.007. However, the $R$ and $A$ used to calculate each trio have since been 'lost'. For each trio, I would like to know the values of $R$ and $A$ given $P(X=0),  P(X=1),  P(X=2)$.

I suppose this involves solving 2 simultaneous equations:

$0.99^R$ $\cdot$ $0.01^A$ = $P(X=0)$

$0.01^R$ $\cdot$ $0.99^A$ = $P(X = 2)$

I am unsure if this can be achieved analytically. Can anyone help?